No Such Instance currently exists at this OID Zabbix SNMP ilo monitoring
I am monitoring a ILO using SNMP through a Zabbix Server 6.4 and using its own zabbix proxy.
Today I got the following alert saying virtual disk is not in OK state:
enter image description here
When I check the 'Latest Data' I get the following message:
enter image description here
No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
I have entered on the Ilo to check if something happens, and everything is okey.
What might be the problem?

Well, what exactly this OID is? What template it is, where you get it? You can look into the item to know better. Maybe, your iLO really don't have that OID, or maybe you didn't setup enough access rights?

I have checked the trigger part and, on the Array Controller Cache Discovery: #0: Disk array cache controller is not in optimal state trigger I have seen that on the Status column it appears as Unknown along with a symbol that says the following: Cannot evaluate function count(/ILO'S_NAME/system.hw.diskarray.cache.status[cpqDaAccelStatus.0],#1,"ne","{$DISK_ARRAY_CACHE_OK_STATUS:"enabled"}"): item is not supported. The template is called Template Server HP iLO SNMP. How can I check the exact OID ?

See inside the item. Just edit it, but don't save changes. There will be a definition of the element, revealing the OID.

Thank you very much, I have checked it, and the OID is the following one: 1.3.6.1.4.1.232.3.2.3.1.1.9.0.0. What else do I have to check?

0.0. at the end look very strange to me. oidref entry implies that there could be no such suboids.

Sorry for the mispelling, but the OID does not end with '.'(dot). So the correct one is : 1.3.6.1.4.1.232.3.2.3.1.1.9.0.0 I do not know if that changes anything

I suspect this is just an incompatible template. I recon item of this kind must be indexed, like ...2.3.2.1.1.9.N, where N is 1, 2, 3, etc, a disc sequential number; there can be no further specifications of the OID, e.g. no dot can come after N. Probably the item was generated during discovery; can you see how it was defined in the template? Likely there will be placeholder in place of my N. The problem is probably the erroneous processing of the placeholder. This is just a speculation, however; I didn't read the MIB carefully.
